# Difference between ままに and ままで?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-で

What would be the difference between

> 扉はやはり音もなく、押されるまま**に**動いた。

and

> 扉はやはり音もなく、押されるまま**で**動いた。

When do you use ままで instead of ままに？

Comment: Interestingly this sentence without either に or で is in the Japanese translation of Victor Hugo's [*Les Miserables*](http://www.jpshop.co.jp/index.php/ja/bilingual-book-ja/world-literature-ja/38-les-miserables-ja/les-miserables-ja-en/490-les-miserables-en-01-02-11-en)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 扉はやはり音もなく、押されるままで動いた。

This is unnatural.
ままで is usually used to indicate that the state is unchanged;
e.g. 凍った**ままである** (remain frozen)